Book about half alien half human kid goes on journey looking for mom
I remember the cover of the book having a six-eyed shark and the main character a kid on top crossing over the shark on a bridge. It was released when I was in elementary school (2009ish) and was heavily advertised in my school. I think the author read a chapter from the book as well.
Another thing is I think the main character's name is Alexander or something like that. But I remember when the guy was reading the chapter the kid had to cross a very long bridge on some vast ocean or body of water. As he was crossing the bridge the shark from the cover starts to make his way to him and in the process is saying "mmm, mmm I'm gonna gotcha" (or something like that) and keeps saying it to scare the kid.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you mean "2009ish?"  Also, where was this?  Since you had a reading from the author that might help localize the author.

Maybe 2009 I don't really remember or what grade I was in at the time.  was at Texas, Houston/ Pasadena area School was Genoa elementary school

This is reminiscent of Michael Moorcock's first novel The Golden Barge, written in 1958 when he was 18. No talking sharks, however.
